# Customer logged out when clicking 'Go to checkout' from basket

Tags: cart, onestepcheckout, magento-2.2.5, checkoutsession

Customers are being logged out when they click 'Go to checkout' before the basket page has fully loaded.

It also looks like guests are having their basket emptied when they follow the same process.

We're running Magento 2.2.5 and using Mageplaza_Osc 2.5.0.

Comment: Please check by disabling Magento caches.

Comment: Is checkout and normal pages  different, I mean HTTP and HTTPS?

Comment: @vish the same thing happens with caching disabled

Comment: @kunj all pages using https

Comment: seems session is being cleared out when user goesfrom cart to OSC page. have you any idea that if there any other module working on session in its observer files?

Comment: @shashank off the top of my head, no but we do have 184 enabled modules so I can't be sure

Comment: @zaq just to be clear, you are not getting OSC page after cart page and getting session out right ?

Comment: @shashank If I click 'Go to checkout' on the cart page before the page has fully loaded I am logged out if I am logged in or my cart is emptied if I am a guest.

Comment: since you have said there are a lots of module to find causing module. I have some suggestions to debug (1) You should check system.log or exception.log if you can find anything there (2) you should check by disabling all plugin from config.php (3) you should check with default theme.

Comment: @shashank nothing in the log files. Getting a 404 when I'm saving theme config so can't update the theme. Investigating why now.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this is a known Magento 2 bug with many stores suffering from the same problem.

I initially reported that the problem happens when you click 'Go to checkout' before the basket page had fully loaded. What is actually happening is that concurrent (quick reload) requests on checkout cause cart to empty.

This can be triggered by a double click on the 'Go to checkout' button or multiple refreshes on the checkout page.

Below is a fix that has been tested on Magento 2.2.5. Please note that this is a temporary fix (**I wouldn't normally edit core files**) until Magento release a full fix.

In vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php replace the regenerateId() function with:

```
public function regenerateId()
    {
        if (headers_sent()) {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($this->isSessionExists()) {
            $oldSessionId = session_id();            
            session_regenerate_id();   //regen the session
            $new_session_id = session_id();

            $_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $new_session_id;

            // Set destroy timestamp
            $_SESSION['destroyed'] = time();

            // Write and close current session;
            session_commit();
            $oldSession = $_SESSION;   //called after destroy - see destroy!
            // Start session with new session ID
            session_id($new_session_id);
            ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
            session_start();
            ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
            $_SESSION = $oldSession;
            // New session does not need them
            unset($_SESSION['destroyed']);
            unset($_SESSION['new_session_id']);  
        } else {
            session_start();
        }
        $this->storage->init(isset($_SESSION) ? $_SESSION : []);

        if ($this->sessionConfig->getUseCookies()) {
            $this->clearSubDomainSessionCookie();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Then in the same file, replace the start() function with:

```
public function start()
    {
        if (!$this->isSessionExists()) {
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('session_start');

            try {
                $this->appState->getAreaCode();
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException(
                    new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(
                        'Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.'
                    ),
                    $e
                );
            }

            // Need to apply the config options so they can be ready by session_start
            $this->initIniOptions();
            $this->registerSaveHandler();
            if (isset($_SESSION['new_session_id'])) {
             // Not fully expired yet. Could be lost cookie by unstable network.
             session_commit();
             session_id($_SESSION['new_session_id']);
             }
            // potential custom logic for session id (ex. switching between hosts)
            $this->setSessionId($this->sidResolver->getSid($this));
            session_start();
            if (isset($_SESSION['destroyed'])) {
               if ($_SESSION['destroyed'] < time()-300) {
                   $this->destroy(['clear_storage' => true]);

               }
            }
            $this->validator->validate($this);

            register_shutdown_function([$this, 'writeClose']);

            $this->_addHost();
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('session_start');
        }
        $this->storage->init(isset($_SESSION) ? $_SESSION : []);
        return $this;
    }
```

Fix taken from https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12362.